# Does GtkAboutDialog crashes when trying to show for the second time

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gdk

I am using a `GtkAboutDialog` to open on a button click. It works fine on the first click but on the second click it just crashes. On the button clicked signal I am just using `gtk_widget_show()` to display the dialog. The about dialog is described in a .ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkAboutDialog" id="about_warehouse_dialog">
    <property name="name">about_warehouse</property>
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="destroy-with-parent">True</property>
    <property name="type-hint">dialog</property>
    <property name="program-name">Պահեստ</property>
    <property name="version">1.0</property>
    <property name="copyright" translatable="yes">  
text 
</property>
    <property name="authors">Grigor Sargsyan &lt;Mr.G.Sargsyan@master-mind.llc&gt;
Int Elligence Group &lt;IntElligence@master-mind.llc&gt;</property>
    <property name="documenters">Artur Tarasyan &lt;Mr.Tarasyan@master-mind.llc&gt;</property>
    <property name="translator-credits" translatable="yes">Grigor Sargsyan &lt;Mr.G.Sargsyan@master-mind.llc&gt; </property>
    <property name="artists">Janik Tarverdyan &lt;Mr.J.Tarverdyan#master-mind.llc&gt;</property>
    <property name="logo">../../data/media/image/Logo/Logo_About.png</property>
    <property name="wrap-license">True</property>
    <property name="license-type">custom</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox">
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout-style">end</property>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
```

I am retrieving the `GtkAboutDialog` described there with a `GtkBuilder` object and assigning it to a pointer for which I am calling `gtk_widget_show()`. I am not sure why this happens. I have not defined any signals for destroying the object.

C code:
I am retrieving the object this way where `main_wind_ob->pmenu_builder` is the `GtkBuilder` object associated with the .ui file mentioned above.

```
main_wind_ob->about_dialog = GTK_WIDGET
                             (                           
                     gtk_builder_get_object
                                                                                 
                            (
                                                                     
                          main_wind_ob->pmenu_builder,
                                                                         
                         "about_warehouse_dialog"
                                                                             
                           )
                          );
```

Here is the button clicked signal which is supposed to show the dialog.

```
static void
on_pmenu_about_dialog_clicked(GtkButton * button,
                                                            gpointer userdata)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  printf("\non_pmenu_about_dialog_clicked()\n");
#endif
    mainwindow * main_wind = MAIN_WINDOW(userdata);
    gtk_widget_show(main_wind->about_dialog);
}
```

Comment: Are you going to pot your C code as well?

Comment: I have added some relevant snippets.